# Error when running same power-shell command on different PC

Tags: windows, powershell, compiler-errors

I am running the following command.

`$ tail -n +2000 text.txt > text.txt.new && mv text.txt.new text.txt`

This works on my HP laptop that uses PowerShell version `Version 5.1.18362.145`

I then moved to my workstation, where I ran the same code, same PowerShell version, but gotten this error

> At line:1 char:41
>
> '+' $ tail -n +2000 text.txt > text.txt.new && mv text.txt.new text.txt
>
> '+'                                         ~~
>
> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
>
> > '+' CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],
>
> ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>
> > '+' FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

I've tried another PC and got the same error, I looked at the versions as well and cannot seem to be finding out why it works on my laptop.

Using this code

`$ tail -n +2000 text.txt > text.txt.new && mv text.txt.new text.txt`

I am trying to remove 2000 lines from the start of the text file

I used the code `Get-Host | Select-Object Version` to find out the versions.

If there is another way to remove those 2000 lines please let me know or if you have a solution to why the same command does not work on the workstation please let me know. (Has to be a single line command)

The laptop is windows 10 Home edition Version 1903

Workstation is Windows 10 Pro Version 1903

Comment: Just to be sure, how did you check Powershell's version number?

Comment: Get-Host | Select-Object Version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` with `-Skip` switch.

```
Get-content c:\temp\input.txt | Select-Object -Skip 2000 | Set-Content c:\temp\output.txt
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, however, after testing it - I found that it leaves me with the 2000 lines at the end rather than remove 2000 lines at the start. I do not know how long the file is so I need to only remove the first 2000 lines.

Comment: This works perfectly in my file loop now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this error?

`&&` is not presently a chain operator allowed in PowerShell (though [here is an RFC which would implement it](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/blob/master/4-Experimental-Accepted/RFC0046-Chain-Operators.md), and similar chain operators have recently shipped in [PowerShell 7 Preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-7-preview-5/)).

Your command would work as expected in the command line, where `&&` does function as you'd expect.

For a workaround, @EyIM has a good solution, but I wanted to explain the error message.